# How to find a point on a line that minimizes sum of distances from three given points?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

Let there be given three points $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and a line $l$ on a plane. Does there exist an explicit method of finding such a point $p$ on $l$, that sum of distances of $p$ from $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is possibly minimal? Such result for two given points and a line is trivial and known as the Heron's theorem commonly used in optics to find a path of a ray of light.

An example of three points and a point $p$ on the line

[image]

All I know about the solution is that if $p$ minimizes the sum of distances, then
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma = 0$$

However, that is not really helpful neither for construction nor finding the solution analytically.
Some rare situations may be solved using [Brianchon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem).

That is, if we add symmetrical reflections of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ on the opposite sides of $l$ and the six points are vertices of a hexagon circumscribing a conic section, then the intersection of the main diagonals minimizes the sum of distances. However it is far from general solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Without loss of generality take the line $l$ to be the $x$-axis. Is your problem not a simple minimization problem of a quadratic loss function in one variable?

Comment: Hi, let us denote the given points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ and let $l$ lie on the $OX$ axis. Then what we wish to achieve is $$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=1}^{3}\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(0-y_i)^2}=0$$. However this is an equation of degree 8, not a quadratic.

Comment: What happens when you use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, the formula above is an equation of one variable. After differentiation we obtain $$\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{x-x_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+y_i^2}}=0$$